# I want to create an event when a radioButton is checked, but i cant

Tags: android, events, radio-button

I am creating a quiz for a project and when the correct answer (radiobutton) is checked I want to change an `imageView` and `textcolor` but i cant get it done.

Below my code :

...

Thank you

Update
This is my code now but it still not working.
Maybe i have some logical error.
I wonder if i can use the | operator in a switch case.

```
    package com.example.android.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

   RadioGroup q1Group;
   RadioGroup q2Group;
   RadioGroup q3Group;
   RadioGroup q4Group;
   RadioGroup q5Group;
   RadioGroup q6Group;
    RadioButton q1R1;
    RadioButton q1R2;
    RadioButton q1R3;
    RadioButton q1R4;
    RadioButton q2R1;
    RadioButton q2R2;
    RadioButton q2R3;
    RadioButton q2R4;
    RadioButton q3R1;
    RadioButton q3R2;
    RadioButton q3R3;
    RadioButton q3R4;
    RadioButton q4R1;
    RadioButton q4R2;
    RadioButton q4R3;
    RadioButton q4R4;
    RadioButton q5R1;
    RadioButton q5R2;
    RadioButton q5R3;
    RadioButton q5R4;
    RadioButton q6R1;
    RadioButton q6R2;
    RadioButton q6R3;
    RadioButton q6R4;
    CheckBox q7R1;
    CheckBox q7R2;
    CheckBox q7R3;
    CheckBox q7R4;
    EditText q8R1;
    ImageView q1Img;
    ImageView q2Img;
    ImageView q3Img;
    ImageView q4Img;
    ImageView q5Img;
    ImageView q6Img;
    ImageView q7Img;
    ImageView q8Img;
    int score=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.sub);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswers();
            }});
        q1Group = findViewById(R.id.q1Group);
        q2Group = findViewById(R.id.q2Group);
        q3Group  =findViewById(R.id.q3Group);
        q4Group  =findViewById(R.id.q4Group);
        q5Group  =findViewById(R.id.q5Group);
        q6Group  =findViewById(R.id.q6Group);
        q1R1 = findViewById(R.id.q1RadioAnswer1);
        q1R2 = findViewById(R.id.q1RadioAnswer2);
        q1R3 = findViewById(R.id.q1RadioAnswer3);
        q1R4 = findViewById(R.id.q1RadioAnswer4);
        q2R1 = findViewById(R.id.q2RadioAnswer1);
        q2R2 = findViewById(R.id.q2RadioAnswer2);
        q2R3 = findViewById(R.id.q2RadioAnswer3);
        q2R4 = findViewById(R.id.q2RadioAnswer4);
        q3R1 = findViewById(R.id.q3RadioAnswer1);
        q3R2 = findViewById(R.id.q3RadioAnswer2);
        q3R3 = findViewById(R.id.q3RadioAnswer3);
        q3R4 = findViewById(R.id.q3RadioAnswer4);
        q4R1 = findViewById(R.id.q4RadioAnswer1);
        q4R2 = findViewById(R.id.q4RadioAnswer2);
        q4R3 = findViewById(R.id.q4RadioAnswer3);
        q4R4 = findViewById(R.id.q4RadioAnswer4);
        q5R1 = findViewById(R.id.q5RadioAnswer1);
        q5R2 = findViewById(R.id.q5RadioAnswer2);
        q5R3 = findViewById(R.id.q5RadioAnswer3);
        q5R4 = findViewById(R.id.q5RadioAnswer4);
        q6R1 = findViewById(R.id.q6RadioAnswer1);
        q6R2 = findViewById(R.id.q6RadioAnswer2);
        q6R3 = findViewById(R.id.q6RadioAnswer3);
        q6R4 = findViewById(R.id.q6RadioAnswer4);
        q7R1 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox1);
        q7R2 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox2);
        q7R3 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox3);
        q7R4 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox4);
        q8R1 = findViewById(R.id.q8edit);
        q1Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ1);
        q2Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ2);
        q3Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ3);
        q4Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ4);
        q5Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ5);
        q6Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ6);
        q7Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ7);
        q8Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ8);
    }

    public void q1Check (){
        q1Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                switch(id){
                    case R.id.q1RadioAnswer3:
                        score = score + (100/8);
                        q1R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q1Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cska);
                        break;
                    case R.id.q1RadioAnswer1 | R.id.q1RadioAnswer2 | R.id.q1RadioAnswer4:
                        q1R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q1R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q1R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q1R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q1Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cska);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });}

        public void q2Check(){
        q2Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                switch(id){
                    case R.id.q2RadioAnswer2:
                        score = score + (100/8);
                        q2R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q2Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.askriga);
                        break;
                    case R.id.q2RadioAnswer1 | R.id.q2RadioAnswer3 | R.id.q2RadioAnswer4:
                        q2R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q2R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q2R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q2R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q2Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.askriga);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });}


    public void q3Check (){
            q3Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                    switch (id){
                        case R.id.q3RadioAnswer2:
                            score = score + (100/8);
                            q3R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                            q3Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.berlin);
                            break;
                        case R.id.q3RadioAnswer1 | R.id.q3RadioAnswer3 |R.id.q3RadioAnswer4:
                            q3R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                            q3R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                            q3R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                            q3R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                            q3Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.berlin);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });}

    public void q4Check (){
        q4Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.q4RadioAnswer1:
                        score = score + (100/8);
                        q4R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q4Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.real);
                        break;
                    case R.id.q4RadioAnswer2 | R.id.q4RadioAnswer3 | R.id.q4RadioAnswer4:
                        q4R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q4R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q4R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q4R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q4Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.real);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct4), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });}


    public void q5Check (){
        q5Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.q5RadioAnswer2:
                        score = score + (100/8);
                        q5R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q5Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.manu);
                        break;
                    case R.id.q5RadioAnswer1 | R.id.q5RadioAnswer3 | R.id.q5RadioAnswer4:
                        q5R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q5R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q5R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q5R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q5Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.manu);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct5), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });}


    public void q6Check (){

        q6Group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.q6RadioAnswer2:
                        score = score + (100/8);
                        q6R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q6Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.anderl);
                        break;
                    case R.id.q6RadioAnswer1 | R.id.q6RadioAnswer3 | R.id.q6RadioAnswer4:
                        q6R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q6R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q6R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
                        q6R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
                        q6Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.anderl);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct6), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });}

        public void q7Check(){

        if (q7R1.isChecked() && q7R2.isChecked()){
            score = score + (100/8);
            q7R1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
            q7R2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radionbuttonstate));
            q7Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ddvspan);
        }
        else{
            q7R3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
            q7R4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
            q7Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ddvspan);
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.correct7), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}

        public void q8Check(){
            if ((q8R1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("reyes") | (q8R1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("felipe reyes")))){
                score = score + (100/8);
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.correct8), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.correct8_1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }

    public void checkAnswers(){
        q1Check();
        q2Check();
        q3Check();
        q4Check();
        q5Check();
        q6Check();
        q7Check();
        q8Check();

        final int plScore = score;
        Intent sendScore = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        sendScore.putExtra("score", plScore);
        startActivity(sendScore);

    }

}
```

Comment: I answered your question, if you will have any issue please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For event on radio button you have to put `setOnCheckedChangeListener` at the group.

**Xml Code :**

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/upcRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UPC"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/prodNameRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/catIdRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Category Id"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/catNameRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Category Name"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="10dp" />


    </RadioGroup>
```

**Java Code:**

```
RadioGroup radioGrp;
RadioButton upcR, productNameR, categoryIdR, categoryNameR;
 radioGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        upcR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.upcRadio);
        productNameR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.prodNameRadio);
        categoryIdR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.catIdRadio);
        categoryNameR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.catNameRadio);



 private void RadioButtonCheck() {
        radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.upcRadio:
                        Log.e("Radio", "upc");
                        editTextSearch.setHint("Enter UPC Value");
                        editTextSearch.setText("");
                        editTextSearch.setInputType(View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE);
                        editTextSearch.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.prodNameRadio:
                        Log.e("Radio", "ProductName");
                        editTextSearch.setHint("Enter Product Name");
                        editTextSearch.setInputType(View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_TEXT);
                        // editTextSearch.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "));
                        editTextSearch.setText("");
                        break;
                    case R.id.catIdRadio:
                        Log.e("Radio", "catId");
                        editTextSearch.setHint("Enter Category Id");
                        editTextSearch.setInputType(View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE);
                        editTextSearch.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
                        editTextSearch.setText("");
                        break;
                    case R.id.catNameRadio:
                        Log.e("Radio", "catName");
                        editTextSearch.setHint("Enter Category Name");
                        editTextSearch.setInputType(View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_TEXT);
                        //  editTextSearch.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "));
                        editTextSearch.setText("");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sample and advice. I ll try it now!

Comment: Try it, If you will get any issue , just comment @Pointyhat

Comment: i did an updated on my post. Check please

Comment: Is your code working or not ? @Pointyhat

Comment: no, the event for the radiobutton is not working.

Comment: First create a demo of radiobutton and understand the things , then impliment

Answer (score 0):

```
myRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //DO YOUR STAFF HERE

        }
    });
```

Comment: Answers that teach the reader are much more useful than a bare code dump.  Consider adding some explanation.